# Remove program from list of installed apps after its files were deleted

Tags: windows-11, uninstall

I have been struggling to uninstall a corrupted app ([Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/)), so I ended up deleting its installation directory. (That was a last resort: [none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77789695/trouble-removing-anaconda3-folder-from-computer-because-fail-to-run-pre-uninstal) of the clean uninstall procedures would work.)

The problem is that I'm now left with the app's "ghost" lingering among the installed apps. How do I remove it from there once and for all? (Obviously, just clicking "Uninstall" fails since it can't find the uninstaller).

I'm on Windows 11.

[image: Ghost of Anaconda lingering among the list of installed apps]

[image: The uninstaller was deleted, so a regular uninstall does not work]

Comment: Either reinstall the app, and then uninstall it again, or use something like Revo Uninstaller